# Split string and convert to int

Tags: android, datetime, split

I'm trying to convert a `String` time to `int` by using code below.

```
public static int SplitTime(String time) {
    try {
        String[] altSplitTime = time.split(":",2);
        Log.e("2",altSplitTime[1]);
        return Integer.valueOf(altSplitTime[0]) * 60 + Integer.valueOf(altSplitTime[1]);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

`String` time holds `Time In : 8:45`
After using split method, I'm able to get `8:45`.

Now I wanted to get `(8*60) + 45` in line `return Integer.valueOf(altSplitTime[0]) * 60 + Integer.valueOf(altSplitTime[1]);`. How can I do this?

Comment: I assume since you are posting that it doesn't work currently... What is the problem with it now? Does it return the wrong thing? Does it return nothing? Is there an exception? The more information you can supply the better chance of getting help you have.

Comment: nothing wrong with my code. Now I just want to split  `8:45`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have two occurences of ":" in 'time', you need to split the `String` into three parts:

```
try {
    String[] altSplitTime = time.split(":",3);
    return Integer.valueOf( (altSplitTime[1]).trim() ) * 60 + Integer.valueOf( (altSplitTime[2]).trim() );
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return 0;
}
```

I added the `trim()` to remove whitespace, just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you split it completely? `time.split(":",2);` would be `time.split(":",3);` instead.

This should provide you with three values in the array with your example `['Time In', '8', '45']`.

You can then parse to int the 8 and 45 to do your calculation.

Answer (score 1):

I would use  `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm");
Date date = dateFormat.parse("8:45");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
```

and then you can use `Calendar.get()` to retrieve `hours` and `minutes` from your String and use `Calendar.set` to set the new values and format the Date hold by the calendar back into a `String`

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(s3);
int b = Integer.parseInt(s5);
```

In your case:

```
public static int SplitTime(String time) {
try {
    String[] altSplitTime = time.split(":",2);
    Log.e("2",altSplitTime[1]);

    int a = Integer.parseInt(altSplitTime[0]);
    int b = Integer.parseInt(altSplitTime[1]);
    return a * 60 + b;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: `altSplitTime[0]` return `Time In`

Comment: as stated in my post ..I'm sorry if it look unclear for you :)